# Property 'response' does not exist on type 'string | number | customInterface'

Tags: typescript

I am working on converting an JS application to typescript and have encountered an issue where the data structure is as follow:

```
{
    id: '46528ed4-1dd7-4d37-b92b-0f1c79dcf92f', // Some guid
    version: 1, // Representing the version og the content
    '104d56d7-f367-46f0-b107-06ebdcd07a4d': { // These objects are fetched from an api and i have no knowledge og what the guid strings that are used to index are
        id: 1,
        html: '<p>Hi</p>' // Some stringified html
    },
    '25c95291-1836-4b01-a537-20223bab1688': {
        id: 2,
        html: '<p>Bye</p>' // Some stringified html
    }
}
```

So i created the interfaces:

```
interface ResponseWrapper {
    id: number,
    html: string,
}

interface ApiResponse{
    id: string,
    version: number | null,
    [key: string]: ResponseWrapper | string | number | null,
}
```

Note that i have to add the `| string | number | null` to not get the error `Property 'id' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'ResponseWrapper`

Now when i want to access the html i have a list of guids which is fetched from another api:

```
const ids = ['someId', 'someOtherId']; // gotten from an api
const apiResonsone = getData() as  ApiResponse // some allready which is of the type ApiResponse fetched data
const htmlList = ids.map(id => apiResonsone[id].html)
```

Here i get the error `Property 'html' does not exist on type 'string | number | ResponseWrapper'.`

I would like to know how this should be typed, i do not have access to change the data structure as my task is only to convert the JS code to Typescript.

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: You are already off to a bad start with "Note that i have to add the | string | number | null to not get the error Property 'id' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'ResponseWrapper" -- you are undermining the point of type safety if you hack the type declarations just to get rid of errors rather then making them what they should be.

Comment: What i was hoping to achieve was a type safe way to have both predetermined props of one type and then some Record<string, type> of another within the same object.

However if there is no way to do this i will just have to ignore the error.

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already off to a bad start with:

> Note that i have to add the `| string | number | null` to not get the error `Property 'id' of type 'string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'ResponseWrapper`

It undermines the point of type safety if you hack the type declarations just to get rid of error messages rather than figuring out the appropriate type declarations.

I understand why you did it. There's no way to say that the index signature type doesn't apply to `id` and `version`.

Oh wait... in this case you're in luck... There is a way since the guid's have a pattern which sets them apart from `id` and `version`:

### Using [Template String Pattern Index Signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures)

With this new feature introduced by Typescript 4.4, we can more strongly type the `ApiResponse` GUID keys. While the `guid` type below doesn't enforce all the rules of a GUID string pattern, it does require it to have five segments separated by dashes:

```js
type guid = `${string}-${string}-${string}-${string}-${string}`

interface ApiResponse{
    id: string,
    version: number,
    [key: guid]: ResponseWrapper
}

interface ResponseWrapper {
    id: number,
    html: string,
}
```